# Where can I find a list of all npm flags / tags / options?

Tags: npm, command-line-interface

I am looking for the meaning of the flag --u as in "npm run test --u" but I don't know where all the flags are documented.

Here at the bottom are some shorthands, but besides "gangster" and other cool ones, I couldn't find `--u`
https://github.com/npm/npmconf/blob/master/config-defs.js#L405

Comment: R u using jest or any other testing framework? -u flag doesn't belong to npm. I think it belongs to jest flags.

Comment: I ran command "npm run test help " or "npm test help" then it gave me all the list of flags with information.

Comment: I went to my project location which had jest configuration then I entered above command. Then it gave all the flags which belong to jest I think..

Comment: Did my answer helped?

Comment: Yes, the project uses jest/enzyme. `npm run test help`did give me all the flags, so -u is shorthand for --updateSnapshot. Thank you, great!

So there are a lot of custom flags, but do you also know how to display **all** the npm flags?

Comment: If you run " npm -l " you will get all the flags list & information you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"npm run test --u" ("--u") belongs to jest flag --updateSnapshot. If you run  **npm run test help** or **npm test help** you will get all the flags of jest.

Inorder to get npm flags list or npm commands you can run this command **npm -l**

Answer (score 2):

Here are the list of other npm flags that you might need:

```
-u or --update: Updates the packages installed in you current working directory

-g or --global: Installs the package globally rather than in your local working directory.

-v or --version: Displays the version of npm.

-h or --help: Displays help information for the npm command.

-l or --long: Shows extended information for the installed packages.

-j or --json: Outputs the npm registry data in json format.

-S or --save: Saves the package as a dependency in your package.json file. As of npm version 5, you might not need this anymore as packages will be saved by default into the package.json file

-D or --save-dev: Saves the package as a dev-dependency in the package.json file.

-O or --save-optional: Saves the package as an optional dependency in the package.json file.

-E or --save-exact: Saves the package at the exact version specified in the package.json file.

-P or --save-prod: Saves the package as a production dependency in the package.json file.

-B or --save-bundle: Saves the package as a bundled dependency in the package.json file.
```